# Oracle SQL Sum missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I have an Oracle SQL that works on MySQL, but I get the "missing right parenthesis" when I run On Oracle.

I put it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5353/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle does not have a shorthand way of using a `CASE` or if like MySQL. As a result you will have to use a `CASE` inside of your `sum`:

```
select p.id, p.name, 
  t.id as toyid, 
  t.name as toyname
from person p
inner join toys t on p.id = t.person_id
inner join 
(
  select person_id
  from toys 
  group by person_id
  having sum(case when name = 'hat' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
    sum(case when name = 'doll' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
) t2 
  on p.id = t2.person_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5353/8)

Comment: thx, that's great!....do you have an opinion if which is better for large scale, yours or [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aed4a/5)

Comment: @bmw0128 Sorry, I am not sure what will perform better, you would have to do some testing.

Comment: I've never tested different SQL that return the same results. Do you mean use a tool that would give execution time, if so, any idea if Toad does this? I suppose I'd need a significant data set to get accurate results? Just wondering in general what one does to compare SQLs that return the same data set.

Comment: @bmw0128 You will want to look at explain plans -- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm